# SwiftData Models support Generics?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-data

It is possible to make a SwiftData persisted model generic?
I'm getting various errors:
[image]

Comment: No. How would that work when it comes to the actual persistence? Every time you used it with a new type in your code a new table would have to be created in the database

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In the case we include an enum in the Model. But after the app is already live, at some point we add a value to the Enum. How would we best approach that? I was passing the Enum via Generic. But that's not possible as you say.